# What could cause the error "Unable to set the Caption property of the CheckBox class"

Tags: excel, vba

I occasionally get the following error when running a macro in Excel:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Caption property of the
> CheckBox class

The section of code where this occurs looks equivalent this:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cbRange As Range
Dim cb As CheckBox

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

[...]

With ws
    Set cbRange = .Cells(2, 2)
    cbRange.Name = "aCell"
    Set cb = .CheckBoxes.Add( _
                cbRange.Left, _
                cbRange.Top, _
                cbRange.Width, _
                cbRange.Height _
            )
End With

With cb
    .Caption = "A Checkbox"
    .Value = xlOff
    .LinkedCell = cbRange.Address
    .Name = "aCheckbox"
End With

[...]

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I am trying to reproduce this issue in a controlled way, but have not succeeded. Hence, I need suggestions of what could be causing this. The only lead I have is that the error seems to occur when I interact with the Excel window during the execution of the macro. The total running time for the macro (the above is just a part of it) is about 5 s.

I do have an extensive test suite that I run quite frequently on this macro and the issue does not occur then. During running I always leave the Excel window alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can reproduce this issue by running the code while the workbook window is minimized. Now I just need to figure out what to do about it, but that's another question!